# How to use C# connect to mysql and get json data?

Tags: c#, mysql, json

As mentioned above:

I'm using `C#` to connect to a `MySQL` database and I want to read `JSON` data type.
I use the method `MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader`:

```
using (MySqlConnection sconn = new MySqlConnection(sqlConnectString))  
{      
    sconn.Open(); 
    String sql_Command = @"SELECT `id` FROM  orders.jsontest;"; 

    using (MySqlCommand scmd = new MySqlCommand(sql_Command, sconn))
    {
        **MySqlDataReader sdr = scmd.ExecuteReader();**  // fatal error
        DataTable datatable = new DataTable();

        // ...
    }
}
```

Can it be that I cannot use `ExecuteReader` here?

Comment: Always show the exact error message

Comment: It's show {"Fatal error encountered during command execution."} when my program run to "MySqlDataReader sdr = scmd.ExecuteReader();"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know [this question is old](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265643/7571171), but just in case you do not yet have a solution to your problem or anyone else encounters a similar problem, the following code should work for you:

```
private IEnumerable<int> GetIds()
{
    using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        string commandText = @"SELECT id FROM jsontest"; // Assuming that `orders` is your database, then you do not need to specify it here.

        using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(commandText, connection))
        {
            MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                yield return reader.GetInt32(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now what you should pay attention to is this line

```
while (reader.Read())
```

which fetches results from the `jsontest` table as long as the `MySqlDataReader` can still read valid results and this line

```
yield return reader.GetInt32(0);
```

which instructs the `reader` to get and return each record of the fetched table [one at a time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield) as an `Int32` (`int`). You need to change this if your tables column type is not `INT`. 
Since you selected just one column (i.e. `"SELECT id"`), the parameter is `0`, because your fetched resul table consists of one column only.

Additionally, in your code you seem to want to get the results as a `DataTable`; if so, you should use `MySqlDataAdapter` instead of the `MySqlDataReader` as follows:

```
DataTable resultTable = new DataTable("ResultTable");
MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
adapter.Fill(table);
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct your sql command

```
String sql_Command = @"SELECT id FROM  orders.jsontest";
```

Comment: there is a extra `;` in the string

Comment: I wouldn't put one in but doubt it barfs due to it

Comment: It's show {"Fatal error encountered during command execution."}